# How to extract characters from text file

Tags: text, unicode, character, non-ascii-characters

I want to extract all characters from text file for create subset font. How I can extract and sort characters?

Example:

input "Hello, Harry. 안녕? 잘 지내니? おはよう。どうもありがとう。"

↓

output " ,.?Haelory。あうおがとどはもより내녕니안잘지"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript, that would be:

```
let input = "Hello, Harry. 안녕? 잘 지내니? おはよう。どうもありがとう。";
let output = [...new Set(Array.from(input))].sort().join('');
// -> " ,.?Haelory。あうおがとどはもより내녕니안잘지"
```

Comment: Depending on whether Hangul characters are written in composed or decomposed form, you may have to normalize the string first in NFC form: `let output = [...new Set(Array.from(input.normalize('NFC')))].sort().join('');`

Comment: That doesn't help, the problem is with `Array.from`.

Comment: Not sure of what the correct expected result is, but the list of code points of the string "ᄀᄀᄀ각ᆨᆨ" is `<U+1100 U+1100 U+1100 U+AC01 U+11A8 U+11A8>`; since the elementary characters `ᄀ U+1100 HANGUL CHOSEONG KIYEOK` and `ᆨ U+11A8 HANGUL JONGSEONG KIYEOK` are different, although they look the same, it is normal they would appear separately in the resulting output string...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -C -Mutf8 -MList::Util=uniq -E'say uniq sort "Hello, Harry. 안녕? 잘 지내니? おはよう。どうもありがとう。" =~ /(\X)/g'
```